# Select nearest specific class when clicking button

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I recently asked just about the same question, but this one got a little twist to it so the answer from my previous question wont work and I'm not getting any answer on my comment.

As the title says, I want to select the nearest divtoexpand class when clicking button1.

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="button1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="THETWIST"></div>
<div class="divtoexpand"></div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="button1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="THETWIST"></div>
<div class="divtoexpand"></div>
```

Old code:

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div.test').next('div.divtoexpand').slideDown();
});
```

This won't work when there is a div in between the test div and the divtoexpand..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looking at your code the `.divtoexpand` *preceding* the parent `.test` `div` looks 'closer.' But you imply that you want the *following* `.divtoexpand` not the previous?

Comment: Is the "THETWIST" element just an example? Could there be more than one div in between `test` and `divtoexpand`?

Comment: David Thomas, correct. I want the following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want the `.divtoexpand` that *follows* the ancestor of the `.button1`, then you're almost there:

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.test').nextAll('.divtoexpand').first().slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().next('.divtoexpand').slideDown();
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ajn/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$(this).closest('div.test').next('div.divtoexpand').slideDown();`

to

`$(this).closest('div.test').nextAll('div.divtoexpand').slideDown();`

[Refer](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)